# two meshes with bump maps wont show up together in Material Preview?

Tags: materials, shaders, normal-map

soo i have this weird problem where i cant get two meshes to show their bump maps at the same time? 
if i hide one, the bump map magically appears on the other one. 
Look at this example with two planes and each one has almost the same bump map added to them. Only one is showing its bumpiness:
[image]
BUT when i hide the first plane, the other plane's bump map shows up...
[image]

Any idea what is going on here?

heres the blend file:
[image]

Comment: could you please share your file (with your texture packed): https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/

Comment: yep totally! [<img src="https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/embedImage.png?bid=0m5GpOQN" />](https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/b/0m5GpOQN/)

Comment: sorry I don't see any problem, everything seems to work fine, maybe a bug on your Blender version?

Comment: hm yeah weird. thank you for looking into it! i tried 2.83 and it seems to be working fineee..!